# Map dynamically array to nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, indexof

I want to retrieve the form content on a submit and map that data into an object.

```
let userData = $(e.currentTarget).serializeArray();
let userDataObject = this.serializedToObject(userData);
```

--
*Template objects to send through POST*

```
serializedToObject(serializedArray) {
        let templateObject = {
            privider: '',
            pop3: {
                host: '',
                port: 110,
                ssl: false
            },
            imap: {
                host: '',
                port: 993
            },

            email: '',
            password: ''
        };

        for (let data in serializedArray) {
        }

        return templateObject;
    }
```

--
*The form of the userData is*

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

-- *While on object is of form*

```
Object: {
  name: 'provider',
  value: 'Aladin'
}

Object: {
  name: 'imap-host',
  value: '955'
}

Object: {
  name: 'imap-port',
  value: 
}


Object: {
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  value: 
}
```

So I need some help to map that array of objects to the templateObject. 
AnyHelp will be highly appreciated.

**Update**

```
[{"name":"name","value":"Nicholas Barbaros"},{"name":"email","value":"george@google.com"},{"name":"password","value":"nicu121-mujik"},{"name":"imap","value":"imap.server.com"},{"name":"imap-port","value":"ad"},{"name":"pop3-host","value":"pop.server.com"},{"name":"pop3-port","value":"465"}, {"name":"pop3-ssl","value":"false"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name-property of each `serializedArray`'s object has a minus-character (`-`) representing nested objects, you can split by those characters and then set the values of your `templateObject`'s properties:

```js
var serializedArray = [{"name":"name","value":"Nicholas Barbaros"},{"name":"email","value":"george@google.com"},{"name":"password","value":"nicu121-mujik"},{"name":"imap","value":"imap.server.com"},{"name":"imap-port","value":"ad"},{"name":"pop3-host","value":"pop.server.com"},{"name":"pop3-port","value":"465"}, {"name":"pop3-ssl","value":"false"}];

// your defaults
var templateObject = {
    provider: '',
    pop3: {
        host: '',
        port: 110,
        ssl: false
    },
    imap: {
        host: '',
        port: 993
    },
    email: '',
    password: '',
};

serializedArray.forEach(function(obj) {
    var deep = obj.name.split('-');
    var key = deep.pop();

    var level = templateObject;
    deep.forEach(function(inner) {
        var nested = level[inner];
        var isObject = Object(nested) === nested;
        level = isObject ? nested : {};
    });

    level[key] = obj.value;
});

// return templateObject; // when inside your function
console.log(templateObject);
```

Comment: not really, my templateObject is nested so this wont work

Comment: Sure, I added the `stringify` version

Comment: What should happen if an object name from serializedArray does not exist in the templateObject?

Comment: it uses the default values.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Isn't my answer working as it stands?

Comment: the final version(object) must be in the form of the templateObject

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reduce method, in a more functional way

```
const array = [{
  name: 'provider',
  value: 'Aladin'
},{
  name: 'imap-host',
  value: '955'
},{
  name: 'imap-port',
  value: 'something'
}];

const newObject = array.reduce( (acc, item, {}) => {
  acc[item.name] = item.value;
  return acc;
})

console.log(newObject);
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y5xkddnn/

Comment: not really, my templateObject is nested so this wont work

Comment: So you can adapt the code to use some recursivity ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is too much overhead to iterate serialized array and map it to the nested object.

Please consider this approach, which is less complicated:

```
let userData = new FormData($(e.currentTarget)[0]);
let userDataObject = serializedToObject(userData);

function serializedToObject(data) {
    return {
        provider: data.get('provider'),
        pop3: {
            host: data.get('pop3-host'),
            port: data.get('pop3-port'),
            ssl:  data.get('pop3-ssl')
        },
        imap: {
            host: data.get('imap-host'),
            port: data.get('imap-port')
        },

        email: data.get('email'),
        password: data.get('password')
    };
}
```

I guessed some fields here. Please correct them if needed.